# Arabic numerals to Roman and vice versa

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have to write a Java program to convert Arabic numerals into Roman and vice versa, but I have troubles with my code,can anybody show me on this example how it should realy look,because i have got no idea how it shoud look like(

```
import java.util.*;
public class Du3 {
static int last = 2000;
static int numbers[]  = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000 };
static String letters[]  = { "I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"};
           public static void main (String[] args){
                System.out.println("Enter your Roman Numerals or Integer number:");
                Scanner cti = new Scanner(System.in);
                String a = cti.next();
                char c = a.charAt( 0 );
                        char a1=convertRomanToInt(romanValue);
                    if ( Character.isDigit( c ) ){
                        System.out.println("Roman value = " + integerValue);}
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Integer value = " + romanValue);

                                }
    static int convertRomanToInt(String romanNumeral){
        int integerValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < romanNumeral.length(); i++){
            char ch = romanNumeral.charAt( i );
            int number = letterToNumber( ch );
            if ( number == -1){
                throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid format");
            }
            if (last<number)
            number-=last- 1;
            integerValue += number;
            last = number;
        }
        return integerValue;
    }
    private static int letterToNumber(char letter){
        switch (letter) {
            case 'I':  return 1;
            case 'V':  return 5;
            case 'X':  return 10;
            case 'L':  return 50;
            case 'C':  return 100;
            case 'D':  return 500;
            case 'M':  return 1000;
            default:   return -1;
}
}
     static String convertIntegerToRoman(int number){
        String romanValue = "";
        int N = number;
        while ( N > 0 ){
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if ( N < numbers[i] ){
        N -= numbers[i-1];
        romanValue += letters[i-1];
        break;
        }
        }
        }
        return romanValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i cant understand how to make this code work,i have tried for some time but didnt manage to do do it(

Comment: You should specify more *what* problem(s) you have. How does this not do what you mean?

Comment: maybe you are looking for https://rekinyz.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/convert-roman-numerals-to-arabic-numerals-and-vice-versa-with-java/

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is clearly wrong:

```
char a1=convertRomanToInt(romanValue);
```

The method `convertRomanToInt()` returns an `int` but you are assigning it to `a1`, which is a `char`.

Then you never do anything with `a1`, but you go on to try and print the variable `integerValue`:

```
if ( Character.isDigit( c ) ){
     System.out.println("Roman value = " + integerValue);}
```

But `integerValue` is only declared inside the scope of the `convertRomanToInt()` method. It's not available in `main()`.

Comment: There is more wrong; the fact that `romanValue` is not defined at all is for instance quite wrong.